# How would I create another incoming rectangle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have made a little game with your player being a car and a car coming at you. I want there to be two cars coming at you but i'm not sure how to start this. I know I need another surface and Rect value for it as it needs to be able to check collision. Also, is there anyway I could get two cars coming at once from one side or is this not possible?

```
import time, pygame, random
import math
pygame.init()
#First Variables
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (100, 255, 100)
ORANGE = (255, 140, 0)
YELLOW = (155, 135, 12)
white = (255, 255, 255)
GOLD = (255, 215, 0)
screenwidth = 500
screenheight = 500
Lines = True
Space = True
color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
doris = []
i = []
x = 247
y = - 20
y1 = 40
y2 = 100
y3 = 160
y4 = 220
y5 = 280
y6 = 340
y7 = 400
y8 = 460
#Display and caption
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Lil cary')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Load in images
bkg = pygame.image.load('BG.jpg')

#Actual player class
class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (12, 124, 134)
        self.vel = 5
        self.grassdamage = 0
        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 100], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (self.color), (0, 0, 50, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (200, 390))
        self.damage1 = False
        self.damage2 = False
        self.damage3 = False
        self.damage4 = False
        self.damage5 = False
        self.damage6 = False
        self.damage7 = False
        self.damage8 = False
        self.dead = False
    def draw (self, win):
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
    def moveback(self):
        if self.rect.y < 390 and self.rect.y >= 0:
            self.rect.y += 10
    def grass(self):
        if self.rect.x > -10 and self.rect.x < 150:
            self.grassdamage += 1
            self.vel = 3
        elif self.rect.x > 300 and self.rect.x < 500:
            self.vel =3
            self.grassdamage += 1
        else:
            self.vel = 5
    def grasshealth(self):
        if self.grassdamage == 100:
            self.damage1 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 200:
            self.damage2 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 300:
            self.damage3 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 400:
            self.damage4 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 500:
            self.damage5 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 600:
            self.damage6 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 600:
            self.damage6 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 700:
            self.damage7 = True
        elif self.grassdamage == 800:
            self.damage8 = True
            self.dead = True
    def death(self):
        if self.dead == True:
            exit()
#Text Setup
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
#Drawing damage bar
def drawbar ():
    if player.damage1 == True and car.damage1 == False or car.damage1 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 50, 25, 25))
    if player.damage2 == True and car.damage1 == False or car.damage1 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 75, 25, 25))
    if car.damage1 == True and player.grassdamage <= 200:
        player.grassdamage = 201
    if player.damage3 == True and car.damage2 == False or car.damage2 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 100, 25, 25))
    if player.damage4 == True and car.damage2 == False or car.damage2 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 125, 25, 25))
    if car.damage2 == True and player.grassdamage <= 400:
        player.grassdamage = 401
    if player.damage5 == True and car.damage3 == False or car.damage3 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 150, 25, 25))
    if player.damage6 == True and car.damage3 == False or car.damage3 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 175, 25, 25))
    if car.damage3 == True and player.grassdamage <= 600:
        player.grassdamage = 601
    if player.damage7 == True and car.damage4 == False or car.damage4 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 200, 25, 25))
    if player.damage8 == True and car.damage4 == False or car.damage4 == True:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (GOLD), (50, 225, 25, 25))
        raise SystemExit ('YOU LOST')
    if car.damage4 == True and player.grassdamage <= 800:
        player.grassdamage = 800
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (50, 50, 25, 200), 3)
    Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Damage", Text)
    TextRect.center = ((65), (30))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


class car():
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 100], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (self.color), (0, 0, 50, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (175, -100))

        self.carvel = random.randrange(5, 10)
        self.damage = 0
        self.damage1 = False
        self.damage2 = False
        self.damage3 = False
        self.damage4 = False
    def draw(self, win):
        #pygame.draw.rect(win,(self.color),self.rect)
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect.topleft)
    def move(self):
        if self.rect.y < 530:
            self.rect.y += self.carvel
        else:
            self.rect.y = -100
            self.color = random.sample(range(250), 3)
            self.carvel = random.randrange(8, 10)
    def collision_check(self, another_object):
        if self.rect.colliderect(another_object):
            print('collison')
            self.rect.y = -100
            self.damage += 1
    def cardamage(self):
        if self.damage == 1:
            self.damage1 = True
            player.damage1 = True
            player.damage2 = True
        if self.damage == 2:
            self.damage2 = True
            player.damage3 = True
            player.damage4 = True
        if self.damage == 3:
            self.damage3 = True
            player.damage5 = True
            player.damage6 = True
        if self.damage == 4:
            self.damage4 = True
            player.damage7 = True
            player.damage8 = True


        #Putting variables to the classes
player = player()
car = car()
#Main drawing function
def redrawgamewindow():
    win.blit(bkg, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (150, 0, 200, 500))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y1), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y2), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y3), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y4), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y5), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y6), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y7), 10, 30))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, (y8), 10, 30))
    player.draw(win)
    car.draw(win)
    player.grasshealth()
    car.cardamage()
    player.grass()
    player.death()
    car.collision_check(player.rect)
    car.move()
    drawbar()
    pygame.display.update()
#MAINLOOP

run = True
while run:
    #Making background and FPS
    clock.tick(80)
    #Quiting Funciton
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
    #Scrolling the lines
    if Lines:
        y += player.vel
        y1 += player.vel
        y2 += player.vel
        y3 += player.vel
        y4 += player.vel
        y5 += player.vel
        y6 += player.vel
        y7 += player.vel
        y8 += player.vel
    if Lines:
        if y >= 500:
            y = -40
        if y1 >= 500:
            y1 = -40
        if y2 >= 500:
            y2 = -40
        if y3 >= 500:
            y3 = -40
        if y4 >= 500:
            y4 = -40
        if y5 >= 500:
            y5 = -40
        if y6 >= 500:
            y6 = -40
        if y7 >= 500:
            y7 = -40
        if y8 >= 500:
            y8 = -40
    #User input
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #Boost controller
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        start_time = time.time()
        if player.rect.y > 200:
            player.rect.y -= 9
            Space = True
    else:
        player.moveback()
        end_time = time.time()
    #Left movement
    if  keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.rect.x > 150:
        player.rect.x -= 5
    if keys [pygame.K_LEFT] and player.rect.x <= 150:
        if player.rect.x > 0:
            player.rect.x -=5
    #Right movement
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.rect.x < 300:
        player.rect.x += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]and player.rect.x >= 300:
        if player.rect.x < 500 - player.rect.width:
            player.rect.x += 5

    #Grass and grass damage

    #MAIN DRAW RECALL
    redrawgamewindow()
```

Comment: What do the `grassdamage` variables represent - damage to the car?

Comment: basically its adding 1 when its on the grass and it will keep going up so at 100 I make the first bar appear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Also see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It is not appropriate to dump you entire development; it is not appropriate to ask broadly how to add a particular feature.  Give it a try; there are many available tutorials on multiple objects in PyGame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty-much there already.  Instead of just creating one `Car`, make a list of Cars.  Where the `car` is draw, collided, etc., now do that for every car in the list.  After some *event*, say 3 seconds pass, add another car to the list.

For example:

```
car = Car()
car_list = [ car ]  # start with one car
car_add_time = 0
```

Now it's easy to add more cars:

```
while run:
    #Making background and FPS
    clock.tick(80)

    ### Add another car after 3 seconds
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if ( time_now - car_add_time > 3000 ):
        new_car = Car()
        car_list.append( new_car )
        car_add_time = time_now
```

Re-drawing the car list:

```
def redrawgamewindow():
    # ...
    for car in car_list:
        car.draw(win)
    player.grasshealth()
    for car in car_list:
        car.cardamage()
    player.grass()
    player.death()
    for car in car_list:
        car.collision_check(player.rect)
        car.move()
```

One other thing you need to do, is change the `Car` class to start the car in a random x-position (but still within the road (... or *not*)).  Since the code just recycles the car back to `-100` when it collides or moves off-screen, it also needs to be re-positioned here too.

For example:

```
class Car():
    ROAD_LEFT  = 150   # this is a rough guess on the correct spot
    ROAD_RIGHT = 300

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        x_pos     = random.randrange( Car.ROAD_LEFT, Car.ROAD_RIGHT )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = ( x_pos, -100) )
```

Comment: Well thank you I assumed it was something along those lines of list but couldn't figure out the time. Thanks